# Android Multiple Button Press

Tags: android

How to make when press multiple keys at same time (like when booting recovery and download mode using power and volume keys) start new activity in android application?

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution, it is tested and it works!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean isVolumeUpPressed = false;
    private boolean isVolumeDownPressed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            this.isVolumeDownPressed = true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            this.isVolumeUpPressed = true;
        }
        if (this.isVolumeUpPressed && this.isVolumeDownPressed) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            this.isVolumeDownPressed = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            this.isVolumeUpPressed = false;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works.Can you just tell me how to make combination volume up + volume up + volume down + home + power + home ?

Comment: @Pavle_nis You're welcome. How many volume up and home buttons do you have? XD

Comment: Two times volume up + volume down + home + power + home !

Comment: @Pavle_nis Such a combo!

Comment: How to make that?

Comment: I created that combination using two timers !

Comment: Congrats @Pavle_nis!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) {
```

Comment: In this example the up and down keys are processed. KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER  try it.

Comment: I pressed volume up and volume down keys at the same time and nothing happens!

Comment: Be sure to run onKeyDown with log.

Comment: No log appears when I press keys!